# module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils' has no attribute 'cached_per_instance'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, classification

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation = "relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))
```

This is the code foe a multi class classifier.
When I am running my model for the data initialized before I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-dcb0cfb9e75f> in <module>
----> 1 model = keras.models.Sequential()
  2 model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
  3 model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation = "relu"))
  4 model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
  5 model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax"))

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
242     # self.trainable_weights
243     # self.non_trainable_weights
--> 244     # `inputs` / `outputs` will only appear in kwargs if either are misspelled.
245     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, {
246         'trainable', 'dtype', 'dynamic', 'name', 'autocast', 'inputs', 'outputs'

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\version_utils.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
 63   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
 64     use_v2 = should_use_v2()
---> 65     cls = swap_class(cls, base_layer.Layer, base_layer_v1.Layer, use_v2)  # pylint: disable=self-cls-assignment
 66     return super(LayerVersionSelector, cls).__new__(cls)
 67 

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in __getattr__(self, item)
 60 
 61   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 62     module = self._load()
 63     return getattr(module, item)
 64 

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py in _load(self)
 43     """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
 44     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 45     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
 46     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
 47 

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
125                 break
126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
128 
129 

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py in <module>
 74 
 75 # pylint: disable=g-classes-have-attributes
---> 76 class Layer(base_layer.Layer):
 77   """Base layer class.
 78 

~\.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py in Layer()
2324 
2325   @property
-> 2326   @layer_utils.cached_per_instance
2327   def _call_full_argspec(self):
2328     # Argspec inspection is expensive and the call spec is used often, so it

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils' has no attribute 'cached_per_instance'
```

Can anyone please provide the solution for this error?
The code works in the colab but while running it in the Jupyter notebook it gives that error. I also checked the layer_utils.py file. It has the Cached_per_instance() function in it then also why is it not found?

Comment: What is the `tf` version in both environments?

Comment: the tf version is 2.4.1

Comment: Try updating `tf` and `numpy` in your local machine.

Comment: @Yash Ingle, Did you tried above suggestion?

Comment: Actually, what is happening that even I installed TensorFlow, it runs for some time but when I shut down the pc and restart it and then restart the jupyter notebook it says 'No module named 'TensorFlow''. Why is this happening?

Comment: It seems tensorflow is not installed properly in conda environment. Can you let us know the steps that you have followed to install tensorflow and version details of python?